# Return value won't change, always returns with 0

Tags: c, function

I'm kinda new to coding, and I have this assignment: I need to write a function in C that checks whether the given string is formatted properly, and if not, it should return 0. The string should contain only letters and the delimiter " - ". So, for example: "aAa - bBb" is correct, so the return value should be 1, but for "a-1 - bB3", it should return 0.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int functiontest(char* text){
   char* piece = strtok(text," - ");  //breaks the given string into 
   int returnvalue = 1;               //smaller strings

    while (piece != NULL) {
        for (int x = 0; x < strlen(piece); x++) {
            if ((isalnum(piece[x]))) {
                returnvalue = 1;
            } else {
                returnvalue = 0;
                break;
            }  
        }                                 

        piece = strtok(NULL," - ");
    }

    return returnvalue;
}

int main() {
    char texttest[11] = "akod - kljp";

    printf("%s", &texttest);

    int test = functiontest(texttest);

    printf("\n%d",test);
    return 0;
}
```

No matter how I change the `texttest` string, the function always returns 0.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: Your break is in the wrong conditional block. If you were to have an integer as the every character, you would see a return value of 1. Basically, what you have written is going to return 0 at the first occurrence of a non-integer. Since you have non-integer characters in your input, it will always be 0. `3` or `333` would return 1, but no non-integer-containing string will ever return 1.

Comment: Another issue you have is that you didn't leave room for the '\0' in texttest. That can make your string appear to have unprintable characters at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your break is in the wrong conditional block. If you were to have a digit as the every character, you would see a return value of 1. Basically, what you have written is going to return 0 at the first occurrence of a non-digit. Since you have non-digit characters in your input, it will always be 0. `3` or `333` would return 1, but `3-` would return 0; no non-digit-containing string will ever return 1.